# Why are only singly and doubly ruled non-planar surfaces found? Why not triply ruled?

Tags: geometry

Is there a reason why there are no triply-ruled surfaces found in spatial geometry?  Does it have to do with the fact that there are at most two dimensions/parameterizations for a surface?  If that's so, then do 3D hyper-surfaces in a 4D+ space allow for triply ruled surfaces?

To be more clear, I am trying to find a proof of sorts that can demonstrate this fact, and whether or not the proof can be generalized to higher dimensional surfaces and spaces.

Comment: The first Google result for "triply ruled surface" gives a book excerpt: "16.5 There are no non-planar triply ruled surfaces." http://books.google.com/books?id=bomkJMq2H9sC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=triply+ruled+surface

Comment: "A treatise on analytic geometry in three dimensions" is a good source too: http://www.archive.org/details/cu31924001521065

Answer (score 7):

Well, one can show that the only doubly rules surfaces are the plane, the hyperbolic paraboloid, and the single-sheeted hyperboloid, and none of these is non-planar and triply-ruled.

Comment: One should probably add the hypothesis that the surface be connected and complete.

Comment: I am asking how one can show this.

Comment: @Justin: the classification of doubly ruled surfaces is given in many textbooks on differential geometry---for example, you can find it in the link provided by Qiaochu in a comment to your question. It is rather too elaborate to turn it into an answer here!

Answer (score 5):

One way to think about the fact that no surface in space can be triply ruled
as follows:

Firstly, one sees that a surface $S$ of degree $3$ or higher is not ruled at all; a cubic surface can contain at most $27$ lines in total, and higher degree surfaces typically contain no lines at all.  (One way to prove this is via an argument with *incidence varieties*; see the sketch in [this tricki entry](http://www.tricki.org/article/Dimension_counting_via_incidence_varieties).)
So a non-planar ruled surface has to be a quadric (i.e. cut out by a degree $2$ equation).

On the other hand, if $\ell$ is a line passing lying on $S$, passing through a point $s \in S$, then $\ell$ lies in the tangent plane to $S$ at $s$.   Since $S$ is a quadric, when you intersect it with a plane, the intersection is a (possibly degenerate) conic section, and so can contain at most two lines.  Thus there are at most two lines on $S$ passing through any given point $s$, and hence a quadric is at most doubly ruled.

Comment: Probably, one should somehow prove that a triply ruled surface is necessarily algebraic somewhere along the way, too.

Comment: @Mariano: Dear Mariano, You mean there are non-algebraic surfaces?! ... Cheers,